# How to solve this linear algebra question

Tags: linear-algebra

Write down a linear system of 3 equations in 4 variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ which has general solution $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)=(2-3t, -1+2t, 4-t, t)$

Comment: Why are people upvoting a question that shows no effort on the part of the asker whatsoever?

Answer (score 2):

First note that $x_{4} = t$. So $x_{3} = 4-t = 4-x_{4}$, and $x_{2} = -1+2t = -1+2x_{4}$; moreover, we have $x_{1} = 2-3t = 2-3x_{4}$. Rewrite the above as 
$$
x_{1} + 3x_{4} = 2;\\
x_{2} - 2x_{4} = -1;\\
x_{3} + x_{4} = 4;
$$
then we are done.

Answer (score 0):

$\left(\begin{matrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}2-3t\\-1+2t\\4-t\\t\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}2\\-1\\4\\0\end{matrix}\right) + t\left(\begin{matrix}-3\\2\\-1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$

Now, we would like to multiply a matrix on the left to generate a set of linear equations, such that the $t$ on the right hand side disappears. Namely, we need to make the rightmost vector zero.

We would need three vectors which are mutually orthogonal and orthogonal to the rightmost vector. We do this by solving the equation:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}-3&2&-1&1\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\\v_4\end{matrix}\right)=0$$

Let $v_1=h$, $v_2=k$, and $v_3=m$. We have $v_4=3v_1-2v_2+v_3=3h-2k+m$.

So:

$\left(\begin{matrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\\v_4\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}h\\k\\m\\3h-2k+m\end{matrix}\right) = h\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\0\\3\end{matrix}\right) + k\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\\0\\-2\end{matrix}\right) + m\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$

The three vectors we need are given in the expression.

Now, we can multiply the matrix formed by the three vectors to the first equation:

$\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0&3\\0&1&0&-2\\0&0&1&1\end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0&3\\0&1&0&-2\\0&0&1&1\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}2\\-1\\4\\0\end{matrix}\right) + t\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0&3\\0&1&0&-2\\0&0&1&1\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}-3\\2\\-1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$

$\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0&3\\0&1&0&-2\\0&0&1&1\end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}2\\-1\\4\end{matrix}\right) + t\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right)$

$\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0&3\\0&1&0&-2\\0&0&1&1\end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}2\\-1\\4\end{matrix}\right)$

This is the system required.

---

And this, is how you over-complicate an approach.